# Quarto: Are there any ways to write a function that can return an entire code chunk or multiple chunks of different languages?

Tags: r, quarto

In Quarto, I would like to create a *function* that takes arguments and returns something repeatable that can be used as code chunks in Quarto, specifically a mix of R and ojs code chunks, but with different values and arguments.

I have tried using the 'child' chunk option and referencing another `.qmd` file unsuccessfully. I have not been able to get this approach to work with parameters- each chunk should have a different ojs variable.

I have also tried using `knitr::knit_child()` but could not get that to work with different arguments.

I have also looked at using the include shortcode, but that didn't work either.

How can I create almost a "meta-function" to create code chunks *and* work with arguments?

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error, I came up with a solution that uses a `.qmd` file that acts as a template, with keyword placeholders, then a meta function that knits that template substituting `R` and `ojs` code ion an appropriate way for each.

The following is an example. It uses a file called `child.qmd` as the template which is called multiple times from `parent.qmd`.

Here is the template

````
# Child.qmd
:::::::::::: {style='margin-left: 5%; border: green 1px solid'}

#### Here are some R chunks and ojs chunks nested inside the same divs
Accomplishing this in a repeatable fashion can get messy. 
Here is one solution.

:::::::::: {style='margin-left: 10%; border: black 1px solid'}
:::::::: {style='margin-left: 15%; border: black 1px solid'}

```{ojs}
placeholdervar_ojs__var1
```
:::::: {style='margin-left: 20%; border: black 1px solid'}
```{r}
placeholdervar_r__plt
```

:::: {style='margin-left: 25%; border: black 1px solid'}

```{ojs}
placeholdervar_ojs__var2
```

::: {style='margin-left: 30%; border: black 1px solid'}

```{r}
placeholdervar_r__tbl
```

```{ojs}
placeholdervar_ojs__var3
```

:::
::::
::::::
::::::::
::::::::::
::::::::::::
````

And here is the file that calls it (including the function definition that makes it all work):

````
# parent.qmd     
---
title: "parent"
format: html
---

:::::::::::::::::::::::: {.column-screen}

```{r init_r}
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
    library(plotly)
    library(reactable)
    library(stringi)
    library(rlang)
    library(checkmate)
    library(knitr)
})

quarto_child_knit = function(template_fl, ...){

    checkmate::assert_file_exists(template_fl)
    l = rlang::list2(...)
    
    # check args are named correctly
    checkmate::assert_list(x = l,
                           names = 'named')
    checkmate::assert_character(x = names(l),
                                pattern = '^placeholdervar_[a-z]+__[^_].*')
    
    doc = readLines(template_fl)
    
    placeholdervars = unique(na.omit(unlist(stringi::stri_extract_all(str = doc,
                                                regex = '\\bplaceholdervar_.*?\\b'))))
    
    checkmate::assert_set_equal(placeholdervars, names(l))
    
    r_varnames = grep('placeholdervar_r__', placeholdervars, value = TRUE)
    stringSub_varnames = grep('placeholdervar_r__', placeholdervars, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
    
    e = new.env()
    
    list2env(l[ r_varnames ], envir = e)
    
    toReplace = l[ stringSub_varnames]
    
    lns = knitr::knit_child(template_fl, quiet = TRUE, envir = e)
    lns_ojsUpdate = stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(str = lns,
                                                  pattern = names(toReplace),
                                                  replacement = toReplace,
                                                  vectorize_all = FALSE)
    
    lns_ojsUpdate
}

generate_meta_chunk = function(template_fl, ...){
    out = quarto_child_knit(template_fl, ...)
    cat(out)
}

plot1 = plot_ly(economics, x = ~pop)
plot2 = plot_ly(economics, x = ~pop, color = I('red'))
plot3 = plot_ly(economics, x = ~pop, color = I('green'))
tbl1 = reactable(iris[ c(1:5) + 00, ])
tbl2 = reactable(iris[ c(1:5) + 50, ])
tbl3 = reactable(iris[ c(1:5) + 100, ])
```

```{ojs init_ojs}
viewof oa1 = Inputs.range([0,10], {value: 1, step: 0.5});
viewof oa2 = Inputs.range([0,10], {value: 2, step: 0.5});
viewof oa3 = Inputs.range([0,10], {value: 3, step: 0.5});
viewof ob1 = Inputs.range([0,10], {value: 4, step: 0.5});
viewof ob2 = Inputs.range([0,10], {value: 5, step: 0.5});
viewof ob3 = Inputs.range([0,10], {value: 6, step: 0.5});
viewof oc1 = Inputs.range([0,10], {value: 7, step: 0.5});
viewof oc2 = Inputs.range([0,10], {value: 8, step: 0.5});
viewof oc3 = Inputs.range([0,10], {value: 9, step: 0.5});
```

```{r, results='asis'}
generate_meta_chunk('child.qmd',
                    placeholdervar_ojs__var1 = "oa1", 
                    placeholdervar_r__plt = plot1, 
                    placeholdervar_ojs__var2 = "oa2", 
                    placeholdervar_r__tbl = tbl1, 
                    placeholdervar_ojs__var3 = "oa3")
```

```{r, results='asis'}
generate_meta_chunk('child.qmd',
                    placeholdervar_ojs__var1 = "ob1", 
                    placeholdervar_r__plt = plot2, 
                    placeholdervar_ojs__var2 = "ob2", 
                    placeholdervar_r__tbl = tbl2, 
                    placeholdervar_ojs__var3 = "ob3")
```

```{r, results='asis'}
generate_meta_chunk('child.qmd',
                    placeholdervar_ojs__var1 = "oc1", 
                    placeholdervar_r__plt = plot3, 
                    placeholdervar_ojs__var2 = "oc2", 
                    placeholdervar_r__tbl = tbl3, 
                    placeholdervar_ojs__var3 = "oc3")
```

::::::::::::::::::::::::
````